# Exit doesn't work in shell script

Tags: shell-script

In a shell script, I have the following code to exit early if the database is offline;

```
Br3trans -u / -c -f dbstate && ( echo Datenbank ist online. ; echo Nächster Schritt... ) || ( echo "Datenbank ist offline" ; exit 1 );
echo Test
```

If the database is offline, it doesn't exit the script and instead goes to echo "Test".

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally writing 'if .. then .. else' constructs with && and || is not a good idea as the && or || command actually only acts on the exit-status of the previous command. As an example, in the construct `command && true-action || false-action`one would expect that the "false-action" is only executed when the command fails. While most of the time this seems to be the case, in reality the || command could also be unexpectedly triggered by the "true-action" failing.

Comment: From the title I thought this was going to be about vi  ;)

Answer (score 17):

The `exit` statement exits the subshell.

If you unroll your one-liner it will start to work as you expect

```
#!/bin/bash
if Br3trans -u / -c -f dbstate
then
    echo "Datenbank ist online."
    echo "Nächster Schritt..."
else
    echo "Datenbank ist offline"
    exit 1
fi
echo Test
```

Alternatively, in some shells you can use a grouping `{...}` instead of a subshell `(...)`, but I think for readability it would be better to use the slightly longer version I've given you.

Comment: Thank's for your help. But now i have a other issue. "line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file", but i dont had a 11 line.

Comment: You've probably missed either a double-quote (`"`) or part of the `if`...`then`...`else`...`fi` structure. Try copying your code into https://shellcheck.net/ and see what it tells you.

Comment: If shell complains about a line beyond the end of your script, it means it ran off the end of your file while expecting some syntax element. Typically: unbalanced quotes, or brackets, of any type: ' " ` { } ( ) [ ] [[ ]]. Or do-done, if/then/else/fi, and so on.

Answer (score 9):

I think your problem is that you have the `exit` command in a `( ... )`-enclosed group, which will execute all commands inside in a *sub-shell* specifically created for that command group only. So, your `exit` statement only applies to the sub-shell and not the main shell used to run your script.

In this case, I would recommend explicit test commands instead of the "one-liner" approach:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if Br3trans -u / -c -f dbstate
then
   echo "Datenbank ist online"
   echo "Nächster Schritt ..."
else
   echo "Datenbank ist offline"
   exit 1
fi
echo "Test"
```

You can still write it as a one-liner if you like:

```bsh
if Br3trans -u / -c -f dbstate; then echo "Datenbank ist online"; echo "Nächster Schritt"; else echo "Datenbank ist offline"; exit 1; fi
echo "Test"
```

Comment: Could also just replace `(` with `{` and `)` with `; }` to make it a command group instead of a subshell (the semicolon is essential when going from subshell to command group).

Comment: @mtraceur yes, roaima also suggested that approach in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568221/377345).